# Manually registering activex exe

Tags: com, vb6, activex

What happens if i manually register an activex exe with /regserver switch which is already registered?

Comment: Most probably nothing, unless you have admin rights (or write-access to HKLM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's harmless, it just re-writes the same registry entries that were already there.

Note that if you've *changed* the COM object ProgIds and such in the EXE in the meantime, it's really important to unregister the old before registering the new, or you end up with cruft in the registry. The registry is quite good enough at "crufting" itself, it doesn't need our help... ;-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder: +1 for the use of the word "cruft".